# Multiple Submit Buttons in HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

For testing purpose I designed simple HTML form as follows

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Form</title>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body> 
      <table border="0"  align="center">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtfname" value="" size="10" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtlname" value="" size="10" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
            </tbody>  
         </table>    
       </body>
    </html>
```

Now on this single HTML page I want to perform basic SQL functionality with MySQL using PHP. I want 4 submit buttons (Insert Delete Update Search) on single HTML form. I tried it by taking DIV tag but still its not working. Any suggestions???

Comment: Submit button will work only in <form> tag

Comment: usman is right.... Submit button will work only in form, you can use javascript and ajax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<form method="post">
<table border="0"  align="center">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtfname" value="" size="10" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtlname" value="" size="10" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <input type="submit" name="insert" value="insert" />
                   <input type="submit" name="update" value="update" />
                   <input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete" />
                   <input type="submit" name="search" value="search" />
                </tr>
            </tbody>  
         </table>
</form>
```

Now you can check which button was used to submit using regular php stuff `isset()` like below.

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['insert'])) { 
    //perform insert
  }
  if(isset($_POST['search'])) { 
    // perform search
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

u mean to ask u want to  perform 4 action's.

just use an ajax call on `onClick` action of each button.

do not create a form, just make a function call.

Answer (score 0):

You can create four forms on your HTML page as following

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<!--  Some form data here -->
<input type="submit">
</form>

<form action="delete.php" method="post">
<!--  Some form data here -->
<input type="submit">
</form>

<form action="update.php" method="post">
<!--  Some form data here -->
<input type="submit">
</form>

<form action="search.php" method="post">
<!--  Some form data here -->
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

from your question I understand above scenario

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

you can do tat using this code...

```
<input type="button" onclick="var e = document.getElementById('form_id'); e.action='adress1'; e.submit();" value="submit1">

<input type="button" onclick="var e = document.getElementById('form_id'); e.action='adress2'; e.submit();" value="submit2">

<input type="button" onclick="var e = document.getElementById('form_id'); e.action='adress3'; e.submit();" value="submit3">
```